# Importing CSV Data As Variable-Value Pairs in Python

Tags: python, bash, csv

I'm trying to emulate the bash concept in Python to have data from a CSV as variable-value pairs. I've a CSV file, which can be made anyway as possible (its up to me). Currently it looks like this...

```
Unit,pixels
AvgVol,87654
AvgLen,5432
```

and similarly a long list of values. If modifying the CSV will make it work, do suggest that too.

I'm trying to read these in such a way that I can access the values like *pixels* using *Unit* or *87654* using *AvgVol* without having to remember their index, similar to what `cat` or `source` would do in bash. Anyways, This is useful so that I can edit my CSV file with the list of variables and their values, without having to worry about their order or anything when referring to a particular variable for its values. I'll later use these for other computations so I can go like

```
if AvgVol>MaxVol:
   print 'something'
```

Any help is appreciated and I hope its doable without much complexity. Thanks!!

Comment: Have a look at [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv` module to perform your task.

Here is an example:

```
$ cat csvfile 
Unit,pixels
AvgVol,87654
AvgLen,5432
$ python3 script.py 
{'Unit': 'pixels', 'AvgLen': 5432, 'AvgVol': 87654}
```

and here is the python program:

```
import csv

csvdict={}
with open('csvfile', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        csvdict[row[0]]=(int(row[1]) if row[1].isdigit() else row[1])

print(csvdict)
```